# Unable to run python code from Linux command line

Tags: linux, python-3.6

I have gone through the explanations given in this forum and have tried them in my program. However, none of the suggestions worked. That's why I am opening this thread.

Below is the tree for my project. There are 2 packages: com and main.

[image]

When I try to run the code for ProcessRiskModelbyRecordID.py from command line, I am getting below error message:

$ python3 /AppDev/XXXX/py/riskScore/main/ProcessRiskModelbyRecordID.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/AppDev/XXXX/py/riskScore/main/ProcessRiskModelbyRecordID.py", line 6, in 
    from main.ConnectAPI import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'

When I run the same code from PyDev, I am able to execute it.

Below is the import code from ProcessRiskModelbyRecordID.py:

from main.ConnectAPI import *
from com import DBOperations as DBO,SourceProfile,TargetProfile

Can you please help so that I can run this code from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyDev is probably setting `PYTHONPATH` for you. On the command line you would need to set it yourself:

```
cd riskScore 
export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`
python3 main/ProcessRiskModelbyRecordID.py
```